# X11 doesn't properly link with CMAKE -> DSO missing from command line

Tags: c++, cmake, gtk, x11

This actually seems like a common question and I thought I found the answer but for some reason it isn't working.  I have a project that uses GTK2 libraries and when first compiling and linking I received the error "libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line".  Some searching through other questions and I found this exact question.  X11 was not indirectly linked, so I needed to add it to my CMakeLists file as well.  Now cmake finds my X11 package but for some reason I still receive the error, any ideas?

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
#####################################
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0) 
project (opencvtest)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(X11 REQUIRED gdk-x11-2.0)
include_directories(${X11_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${X11_LIBRARIES})
pkg_check_modules(GTK2 REQUIRED gtk+-2.0)
include_directories(${GTK2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTK2_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${GTK2_CFLAGS_OTHER})
IF  ( OpenCV_FOUND AND AND GTK2_FOUND AND X11_FOUND)
    add_executable (main main.cpp)
ELSE()
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "LIBRARIES MISSING!")
ENDIF()
#####################################
```

Also, a side question.  I have seen a variety of variables used for libraries and include directories.  For example, above GTK2 uses GTK2_LIBRARY_DIRS while X11 uses X11_LIBRARIES.  Also, more subtly, X11_INCLUDE_DIR vs GTK2_INCLUDE_DIRS.  I've tried X11 either way but get the same results, however I only find other examples of people using what I have above so I stuck with it.  Is there a standard that should be followed or does it vary by package?  Where do you go to know what variables to use with what package?

---

Also, an additional note:  Reading the other questions I found that pkg-config can be used to see what other libraries need included, such as so:

```
pkg-config --print-requires --print-requires-private gtk+-2.0

gdk-x11-2.0
atk
cairo
gdk-pixbuf-2.0
gio-2.0
pangoft2
```

but if I use it as shown in my CMakeLists.txt, shouldn't it handle the linking for me?  Otherwise, what's the difference between using "find_package(X11 REQUIRED)" and "pkg_check_modules(X11 REQUIRED)"?  I'm sorry, I'm following other examples and am doing more reading now, but I would think that package config should handle this for me?

---

Another edit, reading some other posts it seems the 'target_link_libraries' is preferred over the 'link_directories' so I moved them all over and also tried using '-lX11', even though it's probably redundant.

```
#####################################
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0) 
project (opencvtest)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

pkg_check_modules(X11 REQUIRED gdk-x11-2.0)
include_directories(${X11_INCLUDE_DIR})

pkg_check_modules(GTK2 REQUIRED gtk+-2.0)
include_directories(${GTK2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${GTK2_CFLAGS_OTHER})

add_executable (main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (main 
    ${X11_LIBRARIES}
    ${GTK2_LIBRARY_DIRS}
    -lX11
)
#####################################
```

Still same result:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'gtk_init_check'
//usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:140: recipe for target 'main' failed
make[2]: *** [main] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/main.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:76: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, if I comment out 'gtk_init_check' in my program it makes without error.  Probably is all this hoopla is for that one specific function.

Comment: Too many questions scattered through the question post. BTW, instead of linking with  `GTK2_LIBRARY_DIRS` variable's value you should use `GTK2_LIBRARIES` one.

Comment: You're the winner.  The X11 error had me going down the wrong path.  And in actuality, an old post I was reading had the same mistake (that's where I copied it from) and it was never corrected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tsyvarev is correct, the error message while making was very misleading.  I actually had the incorrect linking for the GTK2 libraries, but the error produced during making was regarding the X11 library linking.  In actuality, the following cmake file worked fine:

```
#####################################
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0) 
project (opencvtest)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK2 REQUIRED gtk+-2.0)
include_directories(${GTK2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${GTK2_CFLAGS_OTHER})
add_executable (main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (main 
    ${GTK2_LIBRARIES}
)
#####################################
```

Which also answers my other questions.  Yes, the PkgConfig does handle the library dependencies of GTK2, IF (my mistake), you link the libraries correctly!